# How to register shortcuts so they are also visible in menu?

Tags: scripting, add-on, shortcut

I have already created few simple addons and managed to assign new shortcuts so they are working and appear in the User Preferences-Input.

But alas, I'm not able to make them visible in any menu entry nor in tooltips the way like all other shortcuts in Blender, viz picture...

[image]

Example of code I use to register shortcuts...

```
def menu_func(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_DEFAULT'
    layout.operator("outliner.isolate_selection", icon='RESTRICT_VIEW_OFF')
    layout.operator("outliner.update_default_group", icon='FILE_REFRESH')
    layout.operator("outliner.remove_from_groups", icon='X')
    layout.operator("outliner.add_to_new_group", icon='GROUP')
    layout.separator()

addon_keymaps = []

def register_keymaps():
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager

    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name="Outliner", space_type="OUTLINER")
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new("outliner.isolate_selection", "Q", "PRESS", shift=False)
    addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))

    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name="Outliner", space_type="OUTLINER")
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new("outliner.update_default_group", "U", "PRESS", shift=False)
    addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))

    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name="Outliner", space_type="OUTLINER")
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new("outliner.add_to_new_group", "N", "PRESS", shift=False)
    addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))

def unregister_keymaps():
    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi) 


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.OUTLINER_MT_view.prepend(menu_func)
    register_keymaps()

def unregister():
    unregister_keymaps()
    bpy.types.OUTLINER_MT_view.remove(menu_func)
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Any idea how to make addon shortcuts visible in the menu like all other Blender shortcuts?

Comment: I have removed the line `layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_DEFAULT'` and all custom shortcuts finally appeared in the menu items.

However, I'm still not sure what is the exact purpose of that line. It appears in many examples, yet it seems all works the same without it.